# Why does gvlma() give contradictory results for linear model assumptions?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, linear-model, assumptions, regression-strategies

I have fitted a linear model and I am checking the assumptions for which I get this diagnostic plot:

[image]

From this diagnostic plot there seems to be an increasing variance in the residuals for increasing predicted values, so the homoscedasticity assumption is not met.

However, applying the `gvlma` function of the library `gvlma` to the linear model gives me the following output:

```
ASSESSMENT OF THE LINEAR MODEL ASSUMPTIONS
USING THE GLOBAL TEST ON 4 DEGREES-OF-FREEDOM:
Level of Significance =  0.05 

Call:
 gvlma(x = model) 

                      Value p-value                Decision
Global Stat        1.644390  0.8008 Assumptions acceptable.
Skewness           1.520800  0.2175 Assumptions acceptable.
Kurtosis           0.097512  0.7548 Assumptions acceptable.
Link Function      0.003892  0.9503 Assumptions acceptable.
Heteroscedasticity 0.022187  0.8816 Assumptions acceptable.
```

The test concludes that all assumptions are met, and moreover the homoscedasticity assumption has a quite high p-value. Yet the visual data contradicts these results.

So, the question is what should I trust: the diagnostic plot or `gvlma`?

Comment: Maybe too few observations to get high power?  I guess what to do depends on what you willuse the model for. Specifically, if you want to make predictions, maybe better to model hereroskedasticity